# How to define an Event Listener if the Event Listener class is in a namespace

Tags: php, events, laravel, laravel-4

When defining a [Event Listener in a Class](http://laravel.com/docs/events#using-classes-as-listeners) and if the Class happens to be in a namespace, how should I defined the listener using the `Event::listen` method?

```
namespace MyApp\Events;
class MyEventClass{
        public function onUserCreated(){
              Log::info('Event is fired');
        }
}
```

`Event::listen('myapp.createuser','MyApp\Events\MyEventClass@onUserCreated');` throws the following error

`Class MyApp\Events\MyEventClass does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that your namespace is actually being loaded. Aka, somewhere in your composer.json file - are you telling composer/laravel where this namespace resides? If not, that's your first step. You usually need to add it to the psr-0 location, like so:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "MyApp": "src/"
    }
}
```

This tells laravel/composer that your code for the namespace "MyApp" is found at src/MyApp (with your Events folder being a logical extension of that).